# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() groups all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select card.id as id, photo.image as photo
from card
left outer join card_image as photo on (photo.card=card.id)
```

which returns

```
+----+-------+
| id | photo |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     2 |
|  1 |     3 |
|  1 |     4 |
|  2 |     5 |
|  2 |     6 |
+----+-------+
```

If I change `photo.image as photo` to `group_concat(photo.image) as photos` I get the following result

```
+----+---------------+
| id | photo         |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |     2,3,4,5,6 |
+----+---------------+
```

But my expectation is

```
+----+-----------+
| id | photo     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |     2,3,4 |
|  2 |     5,6   |
+----+-----------+
```

i.e. I want to get a group of photos for each card by id

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregate function, like `MAX()`.  It produces one row for each group.  Groups are defined by a `GROUP BY` clause, and in the absence of such a clause -- as in your case -- all rows belong to the same group.  You apparently want to group by `card.id`:

```
select
  card.id as id,
  group_concat(photo.image) as photos
from
  card
  left outer join card_image as photo
    on (photo.card = card.id)
group by card.id
```

Note also that with an aggregate query, standard SQL permits selecting only the grouping columns and functions of the groups.  In your original example there are no grouping columns, so you rely on a MySQL extension to be able to select `card.id` at all.  The code I present above, on the other hand, is standard in that regard (but `group_concat()` is still a MySQL-ism).

Answer (score 2):

you should use GROUP BY with your query to be:

```
select card.id as id, group_concat(photo.image) as photos
from card
left outer join card_image as photo on (photo.card=card.id)
GROUP BY id
```